# Python Queue raising Full even when infinite

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Well, I am a Java developer who resolved to create an application using python 2.7

Basically I am using a Queue to receive information from a UDP port and another process is responsible to pull these values previously inserted out this Queue. So far so good, the only problem is, the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) says that when an infinite Queue is aimed, basically we should send a parameter <= 0 when instantiating the Queue (e.g Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)), however when my Queue comprises around 32766 values, it throws/raises a Full exception..

Could anyone tell me why, please?

```
    while True:
        try:
            self.queue.put(valueToInsertIntoQueue, block=False)
            break
        except Full:
            print('WHYYY? Queue is supposed to be infinite, at least until my memory blows...')
            continue
```

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyFile.py", line 71, in inserValueIntoQueue
    self.queue.put(valueToInsertIntoQueue, block=False)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 155, in put
    return self.put(obj, False)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in put
    raise Full
Full
```

Plataform:

> > > import platform
> > >
> > > platform.architecture()
> > >
> > > ('64bit', '')

Comment: Is `valueToInsertIntoQueue` always the same size?

Comment: The valueToInsertIntoQueue is an object which comprises a dictionary of keys and values (the UDP socket is getting messages in a json format)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, the fact that it's failing at around 2^15 - 1 leads me to believe that it's something wrong with an underlying variable within the queue.  After doing a little research, it seems like it *might* be something wrong with the pipe, although I'm not 100% sure.  Here's a couple of links you might find useful:

http://bugs.python.org/issue8426

http://bugs.python.org/issue8237

Sorry for not answering fully -- I would have commented, but I don't have enough reputation

---

Edit: I took a look at the [source code for multiprocessing queues](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/Queue.py).

The values in a multiprocessing queue in Python are stored in a Python Deque data structure.  Taking a look at the [underlying C source code for the deque](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c), I noticed this type definition for the deque:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    block *leftblock;
    block *rightblock;
    Py_ssize_t leftindex;       /* 0 <= leftindex < BLOCKLEN */
    Py_ssize_t rightindex;      /* 0 <= rightindex < BLOCKLEN */
    size_t state;               /* incremented whenever the indices move */
    Py_ssize_t maxlen;
    PyObject *weakreflist;
} dequeobject;
```

Specifically, notice this line:

```
Py_ssize_t maxlen;
```

According to [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/#specification),

> A new type Py_ssize_t is introduced, which has the same size as the compiler's size_t type, but is signed.

So, my guess would be that your compiler's size_t type is 32 bits.  A signed 32 bit integer has a range of values between -32,768 to 32,767, the upper bound being where your program is throwing an exception.

Are you by any chance using 32-bit Python? :)

Comment: Along the lines of what I was thinking. I've only used the `multiprocessing` queue but even with infinite size there, I fell foul of exceeding the buffer for a single `put`. But also note that the links you have provided are also for `multiprocessing.Queue()` and the failure there is _silent_, whereas this one is giving an exception. Still, not much else to go on :)

Comment: @JGut

I've edited the question with information regarding my python platform, thanks for your help!!